# c++ How to put a double into a String

Tags: c++

Well in java with a string you can do this:

```
int stuff;
string otherstuff;

otherstuff = "I like this much stuff: " + stuff;
```

But in C++ I have no idea how to.

Comment: `std::to_string`. Check out related questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11:

```
otherstuff = "I like this much stuff: " + std::to_string(stuff);
```

Historically (and still sometimes useful in C++11):

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "I like this much stuff: " << stuff;
otherstuff = ss.str();
```

Comment: Could you help me with this now? When do this: Paint::time = std::to_string(x) + "." + std::to_string(x) + " Hours"; I get numbers like: 12513.13513.4362784.1351253.1235123 hours etc.

Comment: @MackenzieGoodwin: If you could write a small example program to demonstrate the problem, and post it in a new question, I'm sure someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

I like using stringstream for things like this.

```
std::stringstream ss;
double dub = 3.14159254;
ss << dub;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(stuff)`. If for some reason you can't use C++11